# PHP Session array not maintained when calling script from iOS app

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking

I have a php script on my server. I started testing it using Postman for Chrome. It worked flawlessly. However, if I make a call to the same exact URL through AFNetworking, the SESSION array in PHP is not maintained.

Another interesting issue, is that if I run the script from localhost using MAMP, the SESSION array is maintained in the iOS app as well.

What could be the problem?

***UPDATE:***
I am using **HostGator** and I have found that the session_id() keeps changing when called from the iOS app but not from Postman. Neither does it change on localhost.

***UPDATE 2:***

session_id() only keeps changes if the app was terminated, and then I call sign in again on viewDidLoad without signing out before the app was terminated.

**SEE SOLUTION BELOW!**

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that is bound to happen. Usually a browser does the job of handling session data. The iOS app calling your edge needs to read cookie data from http header to get the session and handle it manually. So read headers from response,  store session cookies and add them while making subsequent requests. Otherwise they will get stripped.

I don't know how to do that in your iOS app since I am a web developer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Soo.. As it turns out, the problem had nothing to do with my server configuration.

I was making multiple requests to the server from the app, and some requests came back faster than the sign in request, even though that was issued first. This caused the sign in request to have a different session_id() from the other requests.

The reason why this only showed on real servers and not on localhost, is because localhost was fast enough to process the sign in request first.

While, Postman worked was because from Postman, I was only able to make one request at a time.

Sorry, if this caused anyone a headache..